# Connection string for SQL Server Compact - windows home server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I'm using SQL Server Compact 4.0 and hosting the site on Windows Home Server 2011, program is written in C#  - Visual Web Developer.

I've tried every possible connection string variation that I can think of but I keep getting this error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

This is the string I have currently

```
<add name="Inventory" 
     connectionString="Data Source=C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin\WebApps\Site\App_Data\PHSInventory.sdf;"  /  >
```

I've also tried to point to it with `|data directory|`. I've run out of blue links on Google to click on.

> STACK TRACE
>
> [ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.]
>      System.Data.SqlServerCe.ConStringUtil.GetKeyValuePair(Char[] connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, String& key, Char[] valuebuf, Int32& vallength, Boolean& isempty) +1182
>      System.Data.SqlServerCe.ConStringUtil.ParseStringIntoHashtable(String conString, Hashtable values) +188
>      System.Data.SqlServerCe.ConStringUtil.ParseConnectionString(String& connectionString) +128
>      System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +679
>      System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +46
>      System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter..ctor(String selectCommandText, String selectConnectionString) +73
>      DataAccess.FillDataTable(String SQL) +149
>      Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +378
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

DATA ACCESS

```
using System;

using System.Data;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.Web.Configuration;

using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

public class DataAccess
{

    private int count = -1;

    public int Count
    { get { return count; } }

    private string connectionString;
    public string ConnectionName
    {
        set
        {
            if (WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[value] == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot find connection string named '" +
                   value + "' in web.config");
            }
            //Retrieve connection string from web.config.
            connectionString =
               WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[value].ConnectionString;
        }
    }

    public DataAccess(string connectionName)
    {
        ConnectionName = connectionName;
    }

    public DataTable FillDataTable(string SQL)
    {
        // Fill dataTable.
         WriteToTraceLogForDebugging(SQL);
        SqlCeConnection sqlConn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=D:\\InventoryData\\PHSInventory.sdf;");
        SqlCeDataAdapter objAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(SQL, sqlConn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        objAdapter.Fill(dt);
        count = dt.Rows.Count;  
        return dt;
    }
    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string SQL)
    {
        WriteToTraceLogForDebugging(SQL);
        SqlCeConnection sqlConn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlCeCommand objCmd = new SqlCeCommand(SQL, sqlConn);
        count = objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return count;
    }

    public object ExecuteScalar(String SQL)
    {
        WriteToTraceLogForDebugging(SQL);
        SqlCeConnection sqlConn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlCeCommand objCmd = new SqlCeCommand(SQL, sqlConn);
        //calling code needs to cast data (to integer, string, double, etc.) upon receipt. 
        return objCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    private void WriteToTraceLogForDebugging(string sql)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("sql****", sql);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("CONNECTION*****", connectionString);
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your connectionstring be surrounded by quotes? I guess you have to escape the inner quotes.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio / C# / .NET are you using with your application?  Are you able to load your database in the server explorer window of Visual Studio and query data from its tables?

Comment: try `<add name="Inventory" connectionString="Data Source=&quot;C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin\WebApps\Site\App_Data\PHSInventory.sdf;&quot;" />`

Comment: Tried that, same error!

Answer (score 3):

You are using the System.Data.SqlConnection classes, for SQL Server Compact you must use the System.Data.SqlServerCe classes, like SqlCeConnection.

And then you are constructing the SqlCeDataAdapter wrong, you should use:

```
 SqlCeDataAdapter objAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(SQL, sqlConn);
```

or

```
 SqlCeDataAdapter objAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(SQL, connectionString);
```

Comment: I thought I was, i added my DataAccess.cs to the original post. Can you offer anything else?

Comment: Thanks! I switched that - new stack trace in OP.

Comment: Thank you! So now it get stuck when trying to fill the datatable.

objAdapter.Fill(dt);

I did put a try catch around it, I'm waiting on an email of what the exception is.

Comment: access denied, is my guess

Comment: I've gotten 'null reference' and that my db needs to be upgraded to sqlce 4.0 so i'm trying to figure that out now.

Comment: Why do you have two different connection strings?

Comment: Do you have any ideas on these exceptions, or what other information i can provide that would help solve them?


EXCEPTION: {0} Unspecified error [ sqlcese30.sys.dll ] 0.116998 0.086504


EXCEPTION: {0} SQL Server Compact Edition ADO.NET Data Provider 0.117079 0.000082

Answer (score 2):

Your enclosing quotes are off:

```
Data Source="C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin\WebApps\Site\App_Data\PHSInventory.sdf;"
```

Should be:

```
"Data Source=C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin\WebApps\Site\App_Data\PHSInventory.sdf;"
```

Note that your initial string tries to place `Data Source` as a literal *before* the actual connection string:

```
connectionString=Data Source="
```

Where is should be *part* of the connection string.

Comment: Sorry for the sloppiness, I edited my original post, the quotes start at Data Source and end at .sdf.